# Swift: Global variable not updating

Tags: ios, xcode, button, swift, observers

In a file called Menu, I have this:

```
class Menu: UIViewController {
var no_of_swipes = 99

@IBAction func pressedThreeSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
    no_of_swipes = 3
}
}
```

And in another file I have this:
    class Game: UIView {

```
func didMoveToView(view: UIView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var swipes = Menu()

    var no_of_swipes: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            println("\(swipes.no_of_swipes) should be three")
        }
    }
}
```

However when I press the button in Menu, triggering a segue that moves to the second file. The console states that `no_of_swipes` = 0. In // line x, if I remove = 0, I receive an error about having an initialiser. So, my question is: why isn't no_of_swipes 3? I think this is a problem either with obtaining no_of_swipes or with the observer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're not accessing the same instance of `Menu`, but creating a new one. To access that instance of `Menu` in a different view controller you can pass it in.

Comment: @LyndseyScott please explain how to do that.

Comment: You have declared `no_of_swipes` two times. They are different variables. Omit the one on top.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Please could you give a more detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you misunderstood the rationale for `didSet`. This is performed when you assign something to a property. Paste the following in Playground.

```
class Menu {
  var no_of_swipes = 5

  @IBAction func pressedThreeSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
    no_of_swipes = 3
  }

}

var swipes = Menu()
var no_of_swipes: Int = 0 { //line x
didSet {
  println("i have been changed, and \(swipes.no_of_swipes) is what we do not get")
}
}

no_of_swipes = 99
println(no_of_swipes)
no_of_swipes = swipes.no_of_swipes
println(no_of_swipes)
```

I hope it's self explanatory.

To amend according to the comments:

```
class Menu {
  var no_of_swipes = 5
  var subscriber:((Int)->())?

  @IBAction func pressedThreeSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
    no_of_swipes = 3
    subscriber?(no_of_swipes) // for convenience pass the number
  }

}

class MyOtherClass {
  var swipes = Menu()
  init() {
      swipes.subscriber = myActionOnSwipe
  }

  func myActionOnSwipe(swipes:Int) {
    println("Swipes is \(swipes)")
  }
}
```

If you add the following (also in Playground):

```
let c1 = MyOtherClass()
c1.swipes.pressedThreeSwipes(c1)
```

you will see how it works.

Comment: Thank you. Please answer me: How can I code it so that when pressedThreeSwipes is pressed, the didSet, says 'no_of_swipes is three'. Thank you.

Comment: If you could include how to do that in your answer I will tick and +1

Comment: Thanks for the edit. One thing with the init - I get the error 'Initialisers may only be declared in a type.'

Comment: I get what you're doing but it feels too complicated. Surely I should just fix what I've already done. Do you have an alternate answer?

Comment: Thanks for taking back the vote. Go and get your help elsewhere.

Comment: There's no need to be hostile. I'm just asking a question and I find that your answer isn't appropriate.